# Spark Scala Dataframe: How to convert columns into rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Are there some efficient way to transpose columns into rows for big DataFrame in Spark Scala?

```
val inputDF = Seq(("100","A", "10", "B", null),
                  ("101","A", "20", "B", 30)
              ).toDF("ID", "Type1", "Value1", "Type2", "Value2")
```

I want to transpose it into a Dataframe as below.

```
val OutDF = Seq(("100","A", "10"),
                ("100","B", "null),
                ("101", "A", "20"),
                ("101", "B", "30")
             ).toDF("ID", "TypeID", "Value")
```

The dataframe is big, which contains around 1GB data. I am using spark 2.4.x. Any comments on doing this in an efficient way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a union:

```
val outputDF = inputDF.select("ID","Type1","Value1")
                      .unionAll(inputDF.select("ID","Type2","Value2"))
                      .toDF("ID","Type","Value")  // change column names
```